# Cannot see the result whie using Object detection code using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, github, spyder, object-detection

I am using an open code for object detection using tensorflow available from [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb). I was able to run the code without any errors.

However, I wasn't able to see any images after finishing running the code. Usually, once the code is run, the test images will be shown with a bounding box around the detected image along with the name of the detected object. I am not even getting the images at the end. But I can see the test images in the folder. Please help me. I am new to python and testing the code out.

Any help would be appreciated. This is my [Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOUTC.png)

Comment: I have added the github link for the code. I used the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same thing happened me i prefer use cv2 for images can you place this code to research/object_detection path as `detect_object.py`

file must placed here: `model-master/research/object_detection/detect_object.py`

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from distutils.version import StrictVersion
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
import cv2

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops

if StrictVersion(tf.__version__) < StrictVersion('1.9.0'):
  raise ImportError('Please upgrade your TensorFlow installation to v1.9.* or later!')


# ## Object detection imports
# Here are the imports from the object detection module.

from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util


# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')



##opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
##opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
  file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
    tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())


detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

# In[31]:


category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8)

def run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph):
  with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      # Get handles to input and output tensors
      ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
      all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
      tensor_dict = {}
      for key in [
          'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
          'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
      ]:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'
        if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
          tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
              tensor_name)
      if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
        # The following processing is only for single image
        detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
        detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
        # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
        real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
        detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
        detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
        detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
            detection_masks, detection_boxes, image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
        detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
            tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
        # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
        tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(
            detection_masks_reframed, 0)
      image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

      # Run inference
      output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                             feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})

      # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
      output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
      output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict[
          'detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
      output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
      output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
      if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
        output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]
  return output_dict

image = cv2.imread("test_images/image1.jpg")
# the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
# result image with boxes and labels on it.
##image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
# Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
# Actual detection.
output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image, detection_graph)

vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    output_dict['detection_boxes'],
    output_dict['detection_classes'],
    output_dict['detection_scores'],
    category_index,
    instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=8)
cv2.imshow("",image)
```

Comment: Hello @Rifat Alptekin Cetin , I installed opencv and tried your code. A new spyder window popped up and it is loading something from 10 minutes. Is this how it is supposed to be ? The regular spyder window (where I run the code), still shows no images. (no errors as well)

Comment: I could get the result finally. I used the "cv2.waitKey(0)" command at the end and I was able to see the image. Thank you so much @Rifat.

Comment: than youre run code with loop? @monica now you can give me +1

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me, too.  After some research I found the answer on a GitHub site, https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/6684, that advised it has to do with Matplotlib versions.   I commented out two lines in the visualization_util

Commenting out these two lines in utils\visualization_utils.py:

```
#import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg') # pylint: disable=multiple-statements
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
```